# Does an RTGs efficiency decrease?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've got a ship with Radioisotope Thermal-electric Generators (RTG), they're the stock PB-NUK variety.

[image: PB-NUK RTG]

When I right click on them they say "Efficiency 1.0". In reality RTGs wear out over the course of years - I think it's about 100 years. But I've been on a 4 year exploration of Jool and still my RTGs are 100% efficiency... Do they ever wear out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, KSP doesn't implement radioactive decay. RTGs in the game last indefinitely, their output never dropping.

(also, luckily, KSP doesn't implement cancer...)

Comment: My understanding of RTGs is: they're shielded and safe unless they're damaged.